# jQuery: Modify the structure of an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, structure

i have wrote today because i need some help with a simple function in jquery for modify the structure of an input [reCaptcha] and hide the image showed.

The code of the page(s) that contains the reCaptcha plugin is:

http://pastebin.com/Qahph2ZB

Is possible to make this in Jquery?

BEFORE ------------------------------------------------------------>  AFTER

[image: BEFORE] > [image: AFTER]

(Because i have saw a video of a script[Made in Js/Jquery] that make this effect :-(

I have tryed but nothing :-(

P.S: I can't modify the original structure of the page :-( ... I would like to inject the Jquery with Greasemonkey.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Luca.

Comment: But the code is very long and aren't formatted correctly here [I can post in Pastebin but without expiration..] :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS to place DIV elements over the text and the input area of the captcha?

Check out the complete source here: http://gist.github.com/632560

If you modify your code (I am using the code from page 1) to the following:

```
<div id="DivCaptcha">
    <!-- <span class="Instructions" id="Instructions">Fill the captcha.</span> -->
    <span class="Instructions" id="Instructions">Fill the captcha.</span>
    <form onsubmit="return submit();" action="">
    <div id="captcha-container">
        <script type='text/javascript'> var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : 'white' }; </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LfF970SAAAAAFR6KJNsdJX6Itf43k_HWbxRcU4a "></script>
        <noscript>
            <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LfF970SAAAAAFR6KJNsdJX6Itf43k_HWbxRcU4a " height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
        </noscript>       
        <div id="cover-captcha">
        </div>      
        <div id="cover-input">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit!">
</div>
```

And then you add the following CSS to your page:

```
#captcha-container {
    position:relative;
}
#cover-captcha {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:295px;
    height:55px;
    z-index:9999;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#cover-input {
    position:absolute;
    top:96px;
    left:26px;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    z-index:9999;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

It will cover the elements you want covered. You can then use jQuery to show/hide these elements when you want like so:

```
<input type="button" id="show-hide" value="Show/Hide Captcha fields"/>
<script>
    $("#show-hide").click(function(e){
        $("#cover-captcha, #cover-input").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

---

**EDIT:** In response to your comment.. Try this:

```
$("#recaptcha_response_field").hide();
$("#recaptcha_image").hide();
```

Comment: I can't modify the original structure of the page :-(  ... I would like to inject the Jquery with Greasemonkey.

Comment: Woww,congratulations... Thanks again :D :D